# calling WCF client function doesn't work on IIS

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, service-discovery, wcf-discovery

I made a service using the WCF discovery. Everything works fine when it is deployed on a specific port (using VS2010 debug), but when I try to deploy it to IIS it finds the service but can't run any of the methods.

This is the code:

```
 DiscoveryClient discoverclient = new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
 FindResponse response = discoverclient.Find(new FindCriteria(typeof(IService)));
 EndpointAddress address = response.Endpoints[0].Address;
 ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient(new BasicHttpBinding(), address);
 Console.WriteLine(client.getMsg()); //some test function
 Console.ReadKey();
```

When tring to run the `client.getMsg()` method I get the following error:

> EndpointNotFoundException:
>   There was no endpoint listening at
>   http://computerName.domain/services/Service.svc that could accept the
>   message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
>   See InnerException, if present, for more details.

But I got the address, meaning it found it. And if I use the debug deployer (not to iis) I find it in `http://localhost:port/services/Service.svc` and it runs perfectly fine. How can I have it deployed to iis with no problems?

OS : win7 64 bit

config file :

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="RemoteDeploy.Service1Behavior"
    name="RemoteDeploy.Service">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="RemoteDeploy.IService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint name="udpDiscoveryEpt" kind="udpDiscoveryEndpoint" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>

</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RemoteDeploy.Service1Behavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      <serviceDiscovery>

        </serviceDiscovery>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to add the svc mappings to the IIS? (ServiceModelReg.exe -i)

Comment: Could you please post your web.config file, at least where you configure your endpoints. With WCF services more times than not, all issues are related to its configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try to GET http://computerName.domain/services/Service.svc in your browser - either you get an error or service description..

Comment: going to that link in the browser doesn't work also, but going to: localhost/services/Service.svc does work. The findCriteria gives me the wrong address (gives me the full computer location)

Comment: I get same result in browser with computer domain name and localhost - as part of the URI - are you positive computerName.domain is correct, or maybe it's only fragment?